# A basis that simultaniously diagonalizes two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrices $A$ and $B$, assuming they can be diagonalized with the same S, so that $D_A = SAS^{-1}$ and $D_B = SBS^{-1}$ ... how would one find the basis that makes up $S^{-1}$?

I've got two matrices, dimension =  3, and both can be diagonalized with their respective basis. But how do I find one that diagonalizes both?

Comment: Observe that $$AB=\left(S^{-1}D_AS\right)\left(S^{-1}D_BS\right)=S^{-1}D_AD_BS=S^{-1}D_BD_AS=BA$$

Comment: So how does one determine $S^-1$ from that equation?

Comment: Following the proof of simultaneous diagonalizability, diagonalize $A$, collect the eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue, and diagonalize $B$ restricted to each eigenspace.